# Set time in php to 00:00:00

Tags: php, time

I need to display the time but it must start from 00:00:00?  I've got the following but it uses the current time.

```
print(date("H:i:s"));
```

Comment: Can you eleborate a bit on what you are trying to do? It might be me, but I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Aron Don't worry - it's not you.

Comment: I think he wants a "delta" time, i.e. the PHP equivalent of the C# `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: Are you trying to make some kind of timer?

Comment: `echo '00:00:00'` tada!

Comment: My apologies.  Yes I am trying to make a timer.

Comment: I like how I was the one that figured out what he wanted, yet my comment is the only one with no upvotes. =/

Comment: @SpikeX - It happens, I wouldn't take it personally. It's more frustrating when you provide an answer, you're first and it's a better answer or identical to the one selected, and you don't even get an upvote.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yep, I've had that happen, too. *sigh*.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As an alternative to `mktime()`, try the newer `DateTime` class, eg

```
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setTime(0, 0);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');

// Add one hour
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

### Update

The flexibility of `DateInterval` makes this a very good candidate for a timer, eg

```
// add 2 years, 1 day and 9 seconds
$dt->add(new DateInterval('P2Y1DT9S'));
```

Comment: what is the P2Y1DT9S stand for? can explain it in breakdown form? I can't find explanation in DateInterval class

Comment: @Shiro P = period, 2Y = 2 years, 1D = 1 day, T = time, 9S = 9 seconds

Comment: Yeah, the PHP DateTime class (and its related classes like DateInterval) are, in general, really sexy and easy to use... and massively easier and less hack-y than the "old" way of handling dates. This is a great answer to this question, but I also just want to say, to anyone reading this, it's well worth your time to learn how to use them if you are doing ANYTHING with dates or times.

Answer (score 6):

Use `mktime()` if you want to start with midnight for the current date:

```
<?php

echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',mktime(0,0,0));

?>
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
Friday 14th of October 2011 12:00:00 AM
```

http://codepad.org/s2NrVfRq

In [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), you pass arguments for `hours, minutes, seconds, month, day, year`, so set `hours, minutes, seconds` to `0` to get `today at midnight`. (Note, as Phil points out, `mktime()`'s arguments are optional and you can leave `month, day, year` out and it will default to the current date).

The `mktime()` function returns a unix timestamp representing the number of seconds since the unix epoch (January 1, 1970). You can count up from it in seconds or multiples of seconds.

```
<?php

// $midnight = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('Y'));
// The above is equivalent to below
$midnight = mktime(0,0,0);

echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$midnight)."\n";
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$midnight+60)."\n"; // One minute
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$midnight+(60*60))."\n"; // One hour

?>
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
Friday 14th of October 2011 12:00:00 AM
Friday 14th of October 2011 12:01:00 AM
Friday 14th of October 2011 01:00:00 AM
```

http://codepad.org/FTr98z1n

Comment: You know you can omit the month, day and year arguments to `mktime()` if you wish to use the current values

Comment: See ladenedge's answer. You just leave them out, passing only three arguments

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`date()` uses the current time when you don't pass in an explicit timestamp.  See the optional argument in the [`date` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

If you want to explicitly format midnight, use:

```
date("H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use this syntax:

```
print(date("H:i:s", 0));
```

or

```
print(date("H:i:s", 10)); // 10 seconds
```

Comment: Be careful as `date()` is timezone sensitive. 0 or 10 seconds past midnight on Jan 1, 1970 will look totally different depending on your timezone

Comment: The meaning of 0 will change depending on your version of PHP.  Starting with 5.1.0, 0 means Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54.

Comment: yeah, for UNIX time he should use mktime(...)

Comment: @ladenedge Nope, 0 still corresponds to midnight, Jan 1 1970 GMT. Unix timestamps are signed integers

Comment: Well shut my mouth.  Good catch, Phil.