# Modify a timestamp to another timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a unix timestamp as follows: `1561420800` which results in `Monday, June 24, 2019 8:00:00 PM`.

What I want is to use the timestamp so i can recreate a new timestamp and obtain the month and year and then results in `Monday, June 24, 2019 00:00:00 AM`

You can see the hours, minutes, and seconds are all `00` and its in the `AM`

If its possible in the `DateTime` object id prefer that. I cannot find any examples on the api https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768716/set-time-in-php-to-000000) what you are after?

Comment: @NigelRen i need to use the previous timestamp and modify it to have `00:00:00` as the hours/minutes/seconds

Comment: Does `date("l, F j, Y 00:00:00 \A\M", 1561420800)` not work for you?  You probably want to think about this a little more... why are you truncating the time?  Do you really want to shift by a timezone and then get the date?

Comment: the value `1561420800` corresponds to `'2019-06-25 00:00:00' UTC`, so the time zone offset is going to need to be set appropriately (to get an offset of `-4:00`) if we wan to get that represented as `'2019-06-24 20:00:00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DateTime you can do the following...

```
$timestamp = 1561420800;
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $timestamp);
$dt->settime(0,0,0);
print_r($dt);
```

which shows the time set as

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-25 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

Comment: to get that represented as `'2019-06-24 20:00'` the effective time zone offset will need to be -04:00 from UTC